# Rails form multiple params XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, webforms

I have a form (snippet)

```
<% form_for(@transfer, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :source %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :source %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :destination %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :destination %>
  </p>

  <% fields_for :upload do |u| %>
    <p>
      <%= u.label :upload %><br />
      <%= u.text_field :upload %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', transfers_path %>
```

So now in my transfers controller I can do:

```
@transfer = Transfer.new(params[:transfer])
@upload   = Upload.find_or_create_by_md5(params[:upload])
```

I am able to post to a single form with XML by simply changing the params to XML like

```
<transfer>
    <source>foo</source>
    <destination>bar</destination>
</transfer>
```

or

```
<upload>
    <upload>baz</upload>
</upload>
```

But I cannot figure out how to combine them under the same XML root

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Rails 2.3.x, you might want to look into adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your `Transfer` model. See [what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I saw that, but my problem is that I don't necessarily want to create a new Upload for each Transfer.  If that Upload already exists (by way of it's md5 attribute), I want to use an existing one.  

The next line in that code is:
`@upload.transfers.push @transfer`

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't been able to figure out how to do this for XML, so for now I've had to settle for doing it with REST.  I came across the RestClient library and looking through the source, figured out you could do nested params like this:

```
RestClient.post( url, 
  { 
    :transfer => {
    :path => '/foo/bar',
    :owner => 'that_guy',
    :group => 'those_guys'
  },
  :upload => {
    :file => File.new(path)
  }
})
```

Send a note to the author about documenting the functionality [here](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client/issues/issue/18)